# Maven fails to download dependencies

Tags: maven, wildfly, maven-ant-tasks

```
[artifact:dependencies] Transferring 20K from abc
[artifact:dependencies] Downloading: javax/xml/bind/jaxb-api-parent/2.3.1/jaxb-api-parent-2.3.1.pom from repository abc at http://example.com:8081/repository/public/
[artifact:dependencies] Transferring 8K from abc
[artifact:dependencies] Downloading: org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.1/jaxb-runtime-2.3.1.pom from repository abc at http://example.com:8081/repository/public/
[artifact:dependencies] Transferring 8K from abc
[artifact:dependencies] Downloading: com/sun/xml/bind/mvn/jaxb-runtime-parent/2.3.1/jaxb-runtime-parent-2.3.1.pom from repository abc at http://example.com:8081/repository/public/
[artifact:dependencies] Transferring 3K from abc
[artifact:dependencies] Downloading: com/sun/xml/bind/mvn/jaxb-parent/2.3.1/jaxb-parent-2.3.1.pom from repository abc at http://example.com:8081/repository/public/
[artifact:dependencies] Transferring 40K from abc
[artifact:dependencies] Downloading: com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-bom-ext/2.3.1/jaxb-bom-ext-2.3.1.pom from repository releases.java.net at http://maven.java.net/content/repositories/releases/
[artifact:dependencies] Transferring 0K from releases.java.net
[artifact:dependencies] [WARNING] *** CHECKSUM FAILED - Checksum failed on download: local = '8b9bea8c8373e3f0386e14134443c1873e3cf219'; remote = '<html>
[artifact:dependencies] <head><title>301' - RETRYING
[artifact:dependencies] Downloading: com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-bom-ext/2.3.1/jaxb-bom-ext-2.3.1.pom from repository releases.java.net at http://maven.java.net/content/repositories/releases/
[artifact:dependencies] Transferring 0K from releases.java.net
[artifact:dependencies] [WARNING] *** CHECKSUM FAILED - Checksum failed on download: local = '8b9bea8c8373e3f0386e14134443c1873e3cf219'; remote = '<html>
[artifact:dependencies] <head><title>301' - IGNORING
[artifact:dependencies] An error has occurred while processing the Maven artifact tasks.
[artifact:dependencies]  Diagnosis:
[artifact:dependencies] 
[artifact:dependencies] Unable to resolve artifact: Unable to get dependency information: Unable to read the metadata file for artifact 'org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:jar': Cannot find parent: com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-bom-ext for project: com.sun.xml.bind.mvn:jaxb-parent:pom:null for project com.sun.xml.bind.mvn:jaxb-parent:pom:null
[artifact:dependencies]   org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:jar:2.3.1
[artifact:dependencies] 
[artifact:dependencies] from the specified remote repositories:
[artifact:dependencies]   central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2),
[artifact:dependencies]   abc (http://example.com:8081/repository/public/)
[artifact:dependencies] 
[artifact:dependencies] Path to dependency: 
[artifact:dependencies]     1) org.apache.maven:super-pom:pom:2.0
[artifact:dependencies]     2) org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.3.15.Final
[artifact:dependencies] 
[artifact:dependencies] 
[artifact:dependencies] Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-bom-ext at c:\gitviews\.m2\repository\com\sun\xml\bind\jaxb-bom-ext\2.3.1\jaxb-bom-ext-2.3.1.pom
[artifact:dependencies] 
BUILD FAILED
```

We are upgrading WildFly to version 19. Getting above error which I don't understand well.
Can somebody please explain the error ? I am new to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first thing to realize is that the error is about

```
Cannot find parent: com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-bom-ext for project: com.sun.xml.bind.mvn:jaxb-parent:pom:null
```

So I'd intentionally say, even if I dont know what that bubblegateway is, that this POM is not located in your local repository. To find your local repository in eclipse for example watch the maven settings, there should be a path specified.

In this repository folders are like names in your errormessage. So the folder structure should look like

```
com/sun/xml/bind/2.3.1
```

Behind the ":" follows the artifactId. This is the significant name part of your .pom, or .jar file then.

So the file he is looking for should be: jaxb-bom-ext.pom

I'd bet he doesn't find it. Take a look yourself, I may be mistaken.

Now how to get it:

```
from the specified remote repositories:
central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2),
bubbleGateway (http://example.com:8081/repository/public/)
```

He is looking your predefined repositories, I suppose you did setup them in a maven settings file, but you can set them elsewhere aswell. 
Point is, calling http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 wont help anymore because it moved some time ago to the secure site https://repo1.maven.org/maven2 .

Check it out in your browser, the first one will give you a 501. And the latter should give you a running repository where you can find your pom.

So basically all you have to do is, if I'm not mistaken, find the place where you define your repositories, and add the "s" ;)

Good luck.

Comment: I'm running into an issue with this, too. While the `.pom` exists for `jaxb-bom-ext` in the repo, there's no `.jar` file for it, and ant-maven can't proceed.

Comment: EDIT: I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55626392/251914).